# Tomcat 8 - Maximum File Size

Tags: spring, tomcat, spring-boot

I use Spring-boot tomcat in my project.

I have multipart file upload and the limit is set as follows.

```
@Bean
    MultipartConfigElement multipartConfigElement() {
        MultipartConfigFactory factory = new MultipartConfigFactory();
        factory.setMaxFileSize("1MB");
        factory.setMaxRequestSize("1MB");
        return factory.createMultipartConfig();
    }
```

But, if user is trying to load a file of more than 1 MB, it is throwing some exception.

```
led; nested exception is org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Could not parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$SizeLimitExceededException: the request was rejected because its size (4719402) exceeds the configured maximum (1048576)] with root cause
org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$SizeLimitExceededException: the request was rejected because its size (4719402) exceeds the configured maximum (1048576)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$FileItemIteratorImpl.<init>(FileUploadBase.java:811) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase.getItemIterator(FileUploadBase.java:256) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:280) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParts(Request.java:2734) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParameters(Request.java:3073) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getParameter(Request.java:1095) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getParameter(RequestFacade.java:380) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:70) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:121) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:217) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_73]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_73]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
```

I am not sure, how can i handle this exception so that user will get some meaningful error message in the screen.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, but i think you can handle this exception using error page:

```
 // in web.xml
 <error-page>
    <error-code>413</error-code>
    <location>/ErrorHandlerServlet</location>
 </error-page>
 ... handlers for other http codes ...
```

413 - http code for "Request Entity Too Large" error.

Declare ErrorHandlerServlet error page (e.g. create JSP with <%@ page page isErrorPage="true" %> directive) and handle 413:

```
Integer statusCode = (Integer) httpRequest.
        getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.status_code");
if (statusCode == 413) {
        // print message...
}
// handle another error...
```

Comment: This is not working. I am uploading file through AJAX call and getting status code as 500(Internal Error). The exception is thrown at the tomcat layer. Please refer the full trace in the post.

Answer (score 0):

You do something like this:

```
catch (Exception e) {
    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message",
            "You failed to upload, because file size too big " + name + " => " + e.getMessage());
}
```

Catch exception, then push a flash message to user's browser: `redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute()`

This is offical tutorial for handling your uploading process (in Spring): https://spring.io/guides/gs/uploading-files/